# Joint Probability Mass Function and Conditional Probability Mass Function.

Tags: probability

An urn contains four balls numbered 1 through 4, and one ball is drawn at random. Let $X$ be the number on the ball, and let $Y$ be a randomly chosen integer from 1 to $X$.

a) What is the joint probability mass function of $X$ and $Y$?

b) Find the conditional probability mass function for $X$ given that $Y=n$, for each value of $n$ from 1 to 4.

c) Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

For a) I know that the possible values of $X$ are 1-4 and for $Y$ are 1-$X$. So if 4 was drawn then $X$ would be 4 and $Y$ would be any number from 1-4. I don't know how to create the probability mass function from there though.

b) I have no idea how to even get started on, I assume it uses a however.

c) I'm pretty sure requires me to find a, then $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ then compare to $f(x,y)$.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just write it all down?  $X=1 \implies Y=1$,  $X=2\implies Y\in \{1,2\}$, and so on.  Thus there are only $1+2+3+4=10$ possible values for the pair $(X,Y)$.

Comment: Where would I go from there?

Comment: Compute all the probabilities by hand!  It only takes a few seconds.  To get the pair $(X,Y)=(1,1)$ for example you just need $X=1$, so $P(1,1)=\frac 14$.  And so on.

Comment: So for X = 2 the probability would be P(2,1) or P(2,2) = 1/8? And so on and so forth?

Comment: That's it exactly.  By the way, the question about independence doesn't need any calculations.  Informally, "independence" means that information about one variable doesn't provide information about the other.  But, here, if $Y=4$ then we can actually determine $X$ exactly.

Comment: So then how would I create a function using the probabilities? If I'm understanding what you wrote correctly I'd just have to write out the probabilities without doing the calculations, but I don't see how I will be able to create a function from that.

Comment: Listing all the values of a function is a perfectly good way to specify a function.  Granted, in this case we benefit from the fact that $X$ is so very small....if $X$ could go up to $100$ you wouldn't want to list all the values.  But, come on.  I think you should be able to write the value of $P(n,m)$ in an algebraic fashion.

Answer (score 0):

(a) $\mathsf P(X{=}m,Y{=}n)~=~\mathsf P(X{=}m)\cdotp\mathsf P(Y{=}n\mid X{=}m)$ by the definition of conditional probability.

You can determine these two factors from what was given in the problem.

---

(b) Apply Bayes' Rule: $\mathsf P(X{=}m\mid Y{=}n)~=~\mathsf P(X{=}m)\mathsf P(Y{=}n\mid X{=}m)/\mathsf P(Y{=}n)$

Also use the Law of Total Probability: $\mathsf P(Y{=}n)~=~\sum\limits_{\mu=n}^4 \mathsf P(X{=}\mu,Y{=}n)$

---

(c) Yes, that is what you must do.